# Offline windows azure not online

Tags: azure

Is it possible to create a virtual machine and install windows azure on it, so i call it offline windows azure. Not asking for trials of windows azure, i just want own personal intranet cloud for windows azure development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your looking at the portal capability, provisioning capability etc , check out Azure Pack http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-azure-pack/ . This is to incorporate onto your On-Premises DC.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your query properly then there is no way to install your own windows azure on you virtual machine. So for workaround you can have emulator which runs on your machines for Azure Compute and Storage.

You don't have emulator for SQL Azure as it is, how ever you you may use SQL Express or SQL Server

You can completely develop an application offline and then finally make it a cloud project and generate cspkg and cscfg. and then deploy it in Azure.

Check:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh403990.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh403989.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft **Azure Stack** is a hybrid cloud platform that lets you provide Azure services from your datacenter.

Check Azure Stack: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/azure-stack/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Deploy Virtual WAN
- Sign in to the Azure portal and then search for and select Azure VMware Solution.
- Select the Azure VMware Solution private cloud.
- Under Manage, select Connectivity.
- Select the Public IP tab and then select Configure.
- Accept the default values or change them, and then select Create.